# Save Excel Workbook From Access VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013, excel-2013

I am exporting a recordset from an access query to an Excel Workbook.  The export goes fine, and my syntax prompts the user for a filename/location just as I need.  However, the file is not actually saved.  Am I missing a step in the process or what code changes need to take place in order to have this function?

```
    Sub ETE()

    Dim ExcelApp As Object, wbOutput As Object, wsOutput As Object, bExcelOpened As Boolean
    Dim db As DAO.Database, rs As DAO.Recordset, targetRow As Long
    Dim targetPath As String, fd As FileDialog, Title As String, saveInfo As Variant

    DoCmd.Hourglass True

    Set ExcelApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Err.Clear
        On Error GoTo Error_Handler
        Set ExcelApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
        bExcelOpened = False
    Else
        bExcelOpened = True
    End If
    On Error GoTo Error_Handler
    ExcelApp.ScreenUpdating = False
    ExcelApp.Visible = False
    Set wbOutput = ExcelApp.Workbooks.Add()
    Set wsOutput = wbOutput.Sheets(1)
    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("qryTakeDataToExcel", dbOpenSnapshot)

    With rs
        If .RecordCount <> 0 Then
            'Write the data to Excel
        End If
    End With
    Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs)

    With fd
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .Title = "Select Save Location And File Name"
        .InitialFileName = "File_" & Format(Now(), "mmddyyyy") & ".xlsx"

        If .Show = True Then
            wbOutput.SaveAs FileName:=fd.InitialFileName, FileFormat:=50
            wbOutput.Close
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your filedialog code is not working as expected, and because of that, you're not getting a valid file name and location.

If you want to return the file name picked, you should use `.SelectedItems(1)`, not `.InitialFileName`. `.InitialFileName` sets an initial value and doesn't return the full path.

```
    If .Show = True Then
        wbOutput.SaveAs FileName:=.SelectedItems(1), FileFormat:=50
        wbOutput.Close
    End If
```

This would've probably been easier to catch if you'd have used a valid error handler. Use `On Error GoTo 0` to use the default error handler.

Comment: Still not saving the file.  The fd asks for a name and location, and when I click okay, I get an Excel message asking if I want to save the changes to Book 1.  If I manually click Save on this prompt the workbook is saved

Comment: You can try specifying the file location in the `.close` method, `wbOutput.Close True, .SelectedItems(1)`

Comment: That saves it, but leaves a blank instance of Excel open.  No workbook.  What would be the command to close Excel completely after the save?

Comment: That's `ExcelApp.Quit`, but note your code might reuse an already open application